# Counterpart for NUnit attribute [SetUp()] in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, nunit

I am "translating" a NUnit test to Visual Studios unit testing and I am wondering if the attribute `[ClassInitialize()]` in VS is equivalent to `[SetUp()]` in NUnit?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`[SetUp]` corresponds to `[TestInitialize]`

`[TestFixtureSetUp]` corresponds to `[ClassInitialize]`

[Here's the full picture](https://web.archive.org/web/20171015064737/http://geekswithblogs.net/sdorman/archive/2009/01/31/migrating-from-nunit-to-mstest.aspx).